# I am encountering this error AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Tags: python, android, mobile, kivy, kivymd

I am working on this app where I am managing some tasks. The big picture is that I have a list of tasks (here called entities) and I can add as many subtasks to each task. So, I am now trying to relate each subtask to its corresponding task and show it. I am trying to use a dictionary here, but I keep having this error: `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`.

Here is the Python code:

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.list import IconLeftWidget, OneLineAvatarIconListItem, IconRightWidget, OneLineListItem
from kivymd.uix.button import MDIconButton

class EntityDialogContent(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(EntityDialogContent, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class SubTaskDialogContent(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, entity_text="", **kwargs):
        super(SubTaskDialogContent, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.ids.subtask_list.text = entity_text

class MyApp(MDApp):

    # Define the database and initialize the lists and dictionary
    database_file = 'database.txt'
    entity_list_dialog = None
    subtask_list_dialog = None
    entity_subtasks = {}

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('main.kv')

    def on_start(self):
        self.load_entities_from_file()

    def load_entities_from_file(self):
        # Creating the empty dictionary
        try:
            with open(self.database_file, "r") as file:
                lines = file.readlines()
                for line in lines:
                    entity_text = line.strip()
                    if entity_text:
                        # print("Loaded entity:", entity_text)  # Add this line for debugging
                        item = OneLineListItem(
                            MDIconButton(
                                    icon = "tray-plus",
                                    pos_hint={"center_x": .9, "center_y": 0.5},
                                    on_release=lambda instance, entity=entity_text: self.subtask_dialog(entity_text),
                            ),

                            MDIconButton(
                                icon="trash-can-outline",
                                pos_hint={"right": 1, "center_y": 0.5},
                                on_release=lambda instance, entity=entity_text: self.delete_entity(entity),
                            ),
                            text=entity_text[1:])
                        self.root.ids.container.add_widget(item)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("File not found")

    # Setting the dialog boxes
    def entity_dialog(self):
        if self.entity_list_dialog:
            self.entity_list_dialog.dismiss()

        self.entity_list_dialog = MDDialog(
            title="Create Entities",
            type="custom",
            content_cls=EntityDialogContent()
        )
        self.entity_list_dialog.open()

    def subtask_dialog(self, entity_text):
        if self.subtask_list_dialog:
            self.subtask_list_dialog.dismiss()

        self.subtask_list_dialog = MDDialog(
            title=f"Add a subtask to entity: {entity_text}",
            type="custom",
            content_cls=SubTaskDialogContent(entity_text=entity_text)
        )
        self.subtask_list_dialog.open()

# Adding Entities and subtasks
    def add_entity(self):
        entity_text = self.entity_list_dialog.content_cls.ids.entity_text.text
        if entity_text.strip():
            with open(self.database_file, "a") as file:
                file.write("*" + entity_text + "\n")

            item = OneLineListItem(
                MDIconButton(
                    icon="tray-plus",
                    pos_hint={"center_x": .9, "center_y": 0.5},
                    on_release=lambda instance, entity=entity_text: self.subtask_dialog(entity_text),
                ),

                MDIconButton(
                    icon="trash-can-outline",
                    pos_hint={"right": 1, "center_y": 0.5},
                    on_release=lambda instance, entity=entity_text: self.delete_entity(entity),
                ),
                text=entity_text)
            self.root.ids.container.add_widget(item)
            self.entity_list_dialog.content_cls.ids.entity_text.text = ""

    def add_subtask(self, entity_text):
        subtask_text = self.subtask_list_dialog.content_cls.ids.subtask_text.text
        if subtask_text.strip():
            with open(self.database_file, "a") as file:
                file.write(f"{entity_text}: {subtask_text}\n")
                #
                # item = OneLineAvatarIconListItem(
                #             # IconRightWidget(icon = 'plus'),
                #             text=subtask_text)
                # self.root.ids.container.add_widget(item)

                if entity_text not in entity_subtasks:
                    entity_subtasks[entity_text] = []
                entity_subtasks[entity_text].append(subtask_text)

                self.subtask_list_dialog.content_cls.ids.subtask_text.text = ""

# Deleting tasks and Subtasks

    def delete_entity(self, entity_text):
        try:
            # First, read the contents of the database file
            with open(self.database_file, "r") as file:
                lines = file.readlines()
            # Create a flag to check if an entity was deleted
            entity_deleted = False
            # Reopen the database file for writing
            with open(self.database_file, "w") as file:
                for line in lines:
                    if entity_text not in line:
                        file.write(line)
                    else:
                        entity_deleted = True

            if entity_deleted:
                # Remove the item from the UI
                items_to_remove = []
                for item in self.root.ids.container.children:
                    if isinstance(item, OneLineListItem) and item.text == entity_text[1:]: # here it works aslong as things are not duplicated, which is fine in this context becaysue we are not expecttings entities with the same name
                        items_to_remove.append(item)
                for item in items_to_remove:
                    self.root.ids.container.remove_widget(item)
                print(f"Entity '{entity_text}' deleted from the database and the screen!")
            else:
                print(f"Entity '{entity_text}' not found in the database.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error deleting entity: {e}")

    # Closing Dialogs
    def close_entity_dialog(self, *args):
        self.entity_list_dialog.dismiss()

    def close_subtask_dialog(self):
        self.subtask_list_dialog.dismiss()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
```

And here is the kivy code

```
MDFloatLayout:
    MDLabel:
        id: task_label
        halign: "center"
        markup: True
        text:"[b][u][size=48]Task Manager[/size][/u][/b]"
        pos_hint: {"y": 0.45}

    ScrollView:
        pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.5, "center_x": 0.5}
        size_hint: 0.9, 0.8
        MDList:
            id: container

    MDFloatingActionButton:
        icon: "plus-thick"
        on_release: app.entity_dialog()
        elevation_normal: 12
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.45 , "y": 0.04}

<EntityDialogContent>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "10dp"
    size_hint : 1, None
    height: "130dp"

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1

        MDTextField:
            id: entity_text
            hint_text: "Add an Entity ..."
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.4}
            max_text_length: 50
            on_text_validate: (app.add_entity(), app.close_entity_dialog())


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "SAVE"
            on_release: (app.add_entity(), app.close_entity_dialog())
        MDFlatButton:
            text: "CANCEL"
            on_release: app.close_entity_dialog()


<SubTaskDialogContent>:
    id: sub_task_content  # You can add a unique id for this widget
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "10dp"
    size_hint : 1, None
    height: "130dp"

    GridLayout:
        rows: 1

        MDTextField:
            id: subtask_text
            hint_text: "Add a subtask ..."
            pos_hint: {"center_y": 0.4}
            max_text_length: 50
            on_text_validate: app.add_subtask(sub_task_content.ids.subtask_text.text), app.close_subtask_dialog()


    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "SAVE"
            on_release: app.add_subtask(sub_task_content.ids.subtask_text.text), app.close_subtask_dialog()
        MDFlatButton:
            text: "CANCEL"
            on_release: app.close_subtask_dialog()
```

I tried so many things But I am stuck now.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a typo. In the class `SubTaskDialogContent`, should the line:

```
self.ids.subtask_list.text = entity_text
```

actually be:

```
self.ids.subtask_text.text = entity_text
```